# Eclipse PDT - Javascript Code Assist is not work?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I thought PDT would do code assisting on JS files. Was I wrong, or is there a bug or something I am missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse PDT - Javascript code hinting not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896534/eclipse-pdt-javascript-code-hinting-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the Javascript development tools installed? I'm not sure, whether its installed together with the PHP Development Tools.

Select Help/Install new software, then select the Helios update site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios), then install the Javascript Development Tools from the Web, XML and Java EE category.

**Update**: See the answer at your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896534/eclipse-pdt-javascript-code-hinting-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

Got here because I had the same problem, first install "Eclipse web developer tools => javascript development tools"

Then instead of creating a javascript project create a "static web project". Right click the project in project explorer choose configure (in the bottom) make sure you add javascript support (if it's not there than it's probably already supported).

Under your project in project explorer there should be an item called javascript resources right click that and choose properties. If the browser libraries or ecma3 libraries are not there you can add them.