# Eclipse PDT - Javascript code hinting not working?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I thought **[Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/)** had all the Javascript plugins and supported code hinting, but it's not working for me.
Was I wrong, or is there something that needs to be set up for this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official plugin is **[JSDT](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JSDT)** ([Eclipse site](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/)) ([many articles there](http://kellicker.wordpress.com/category/eclipse-2/), including the [Using JSDT series](http://kellicker.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/jsdt-resources/))

[image]

The old alternative was **[JSEclipse](http://www.interaktonline.com/products/eclipse/jseclipse/overview/)** (like [described in this post](http://2tbsp.com/content/getting_started_eclipse_php_development_tools_(pdt)))
Warning, this plugin [might not be compatible with the official JSDT Eclipse one](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=157456&#page_top).

This [forum post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=167393&) also mentions **[Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/)** as an alternative.